# Can Bifrost selectively reject something/someone from its radius?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel

When Bifrost Bridge is opened, it's visible and it is Cylindrical with a huge radius to accept multiple people. I have never seen someone calling Heimdall to beam up these and these people. They all just stand nearby.

Can I jump near Thor (in Bifrost radius) to visit Asgard when Bifrost is opened? Or, can I throw a Nuclear Weapon inside Bifrost radius in order to attack Asgard?

Comment: In the most recent Agents of Shield episode Lady Sif called Heimdall to "beam her up".

Comment: @trysis The point is she didn't call to beam Kree up with her, yet they both got beamed up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Michael said, the Bifrost does not work that way in the comics, so it's not a useful comparison point.  However, in *Thor: The Dark World*, when Jane and Thor head to Asgard, a piece of car tags along for the ride:

[image: Screenshot showing car with front cut off]

That piece of car then comes flying out of the Bifrost on the Asgard side.  Professional teleporter that he is, I'd think that Heimdall would have not hurled a chunk of car at himself if the Bifrost allowed it.  So I think it's safe to assume that the Bifrost in the MCU takes anything in its radius when it's activated.

Comment: One has to wonder why Heimdall didn't target it just a little to the left.

Comment: @zwol Maybe the dude just hadn't had his morning coffee yet.

Comment: @Keen So you're saying he was lazy? 'cause he was alert enough to dodge the flying bumper :P Or that his aim was off a bit, so depending on his coffein intake he might just leave junks of people behind?? :D Hopefully those wounds get cauterized immediately....

Comment: Whats a car to a god? Whats a god to a non-believer...

Answer (score 5):

Since you asked for an answer specifically from the comics:

Unfortunately, the Bifrost Bridge in the comics is nothing like the Bifrost from the MCU. In the comics, the Bifrost Bridge is a permanent portal, which leads from Asgard to Midgard. It appears as an actual, physical rainbow-colored bridge, and though Heimdall guards it, he has no control over where it goes or when it's "up" or "down.

Travelling between realms in the comics does not require use of the Bifrost; in fact, as far as I know, the *Ragnarok* storyline saw the bridge shattered and never rebuilt.